# Как разместить несколько сайтов на одном сервере?

Tags: apache, nginx

У меня в папке /var/www/ лежит сайт, как мне указать apache + nginx на то, что в папке /var/www/t4/ будет лежать абсолютно другой сайт?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поищите информацию по теме "Как настраивать виртуальные хосты в Apache 2"

Вот к примеру

- http://webhamster.ru/site/page/index/articles/comp/9
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ru/vhosts/

Ну и соответственно для nginx.